# how to include custom domain name in the redirection rule

Tags: url-rewrite

We have a redirection rule written on the web config as like below

```
<rule name="x to y" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="x(/.*){0,1}$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/y/z{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The above redirection rule will redirect [www.somesite.azurewebsite.net/x](https://www.somesite.com/x) to [www.somesite.azurewebsite.net/y/z](https://www.somesite.com/y/z) while accessing direct server url.

Now we have added custom domain for the application and above rule is not taking that custom domain it is redirecting from [www.customdomain.com/x](https://www.customdomain.com/x) to [www.somesite.azurewebsite.net/y/z](https://www.somesite.azurewebsite.net/y/z) . instead of this I want to redirect this to [www.customdomain.com/y/z](https://www.customdomain.com/y/z)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rule name="Rule for Somesite" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{StaticRedirects_Somesite:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="www.somesite.azurewebsite.net{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rule for Customdomain" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{StaticRedirects_Customdomain:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="www.customdomain.com{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
    <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="StaticRedirects_Somesite">
            <add key="/x/" value="/y/z/" />
        </rewriteMap>
        <rewriteMap name="StaticRedirects_Customdomain">
            <add key="/p/" value="/q/r/" />
            <add key="/a/" value="/b/c/" />
        </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

You can also use URL Redirect Module for the same. See the blog post: [URL Redirects Module in Sitecore](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2021/11/url-redirects-module-in-sitecore.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the domain to the action.

`<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.customdomain.com/y/z{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />`

If you want to include the request host, you can use `{HTTP_HOST}`

```
<rule name="x to y" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="x(/.*){0,1}$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/y/z{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

None of this is specific to Sitecore tho.